# SharePoint 2013 Document Permissions from AD Group not propagating correctly

Tags: sharepoint-2013

So, I was asked to set permissions on a single document in a document library for a group of users.  The users already have 'Read-Only' access to all the documents in the library, but for this single document, there is a smaller group that will have Contribute rights.

Using the 'Share' feature available in SharePoint 2013, I tested this functionality on this document and a single user (Jane Doe).  It worked as it was supposed to, and Jane had full edit rights on the document. Good so far.

I then added a group in Active Directory, and added Jane Doe, and multiple other users, to this group.  I then 'Shared' this document with the group the same way I did it for the single user.  Once complete, I checked the permissions for a few of the users and found they all had edit permissions.  Again, good so far.

The next step I took was to remove the explicit permissions I gave to Jane Doe early, as she should get the rights from the AD Group.  However, once I removed her, she no longer had edit permissions.  All the others in the group are still working as expected.

I tried removing the group permissions, and re-adding them, but Jane Doe still doesn't have the rights the others in the group have.

What else can I do to get SharePoint to recognize the rights of this single user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general with 2013 permissions, what I have seen is that if you remove a person specifically, it removes their permissions through out.

If adding her individually hasn't worked, I think you might have an easier time if you manually set the file back to inherit permissions. Then check that she has permissions (if she should have it a level up (e.g. at the document library level)) and then manage unique permissions again adding the AD group versus individuals.

I would also suggest that you use the "Advanced" options, as it may show you more clearly what you need to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have been using the advance options to view the permissions and manage them too.  I ended up removing the user from the AD group, and removing the group's permissions too.  Then I re-added the permissions to the document, then re-added the user to the AD group.  It is now working for all users.  Since you were the only one that answered and were on the same path I took to resolve, I went ahead and rewarded you with the correct answer.